# Updating a mockobject is giving undefined error

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am running my test using Jasmine in Angular. I need to update the value of mock object before running my tests. The mock object in question is the mockRoute here.
As you can see in the code below it is currently set as

```
let mockRoute = { params: of({ id: '123', type: 'test' }), snapshot: {} };
```

I need to update it to

```
 this.mockRoute = { params: of({ id: '123', type: 'BankAccountCompliance' }), snapshot: {} };
```

If you see my test marked fit has that line of code above. Unfortunately I am getting error

```
Cannot set property 'mockRoute' of undefined
```

How do I update that mockRoute ?

TestComponent

```
describe('ApproveComponent', () => {
  let component: ApproveComponent;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ApproveComponent>;
  const mockService: ApprovalsService = <ApprovalsService>{
    approve: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
    reset: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
    reject: (id: string, type: string, message: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
    get: (type: string, id: string) => <Promise<any>>{},
  };


  let mockRoute = { params: of({ id: '123', type: 'test' }), snapshot: {} };

  function setupComponent(getResult: any = {}) {
    spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('approve')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
    spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('reset')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
    spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('reject')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));
    spyOn(mockService, nameof<ApprovalsService>('get')).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(getResult));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        DxTextAreaModule,
        DxButtonModule,
        SharedModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'approvals', component: ApproveComponent }])
      ],
      declarations: [ApproveComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: ApprovalsService, useValue: mockService },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockRoute },
        { provide: MessageService, useClass: MockMessageService },
        { provide: ConfirmationDialogService, useValue: ConfirmationDialogServiceMock },
        { provide: NgxPermissionsService, useClass: MockNgxPermissionsService }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ApproveComponent);
    injector = getTestBed();
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn((<any>component).router, 'navigate').and.returnValue(true);

    fixture.detectChanges();
  }

  it('should create and call get', () => {
    setupComponent();

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mockService.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });



  fit('should hide the Reset button when type is BankAccount', () => {
    this.mockRoute = { params: of({ id: '123', type: 'BankAccountCompliance' }), snapshot: {} };
    setupComponent();

    // component.isBankAccount = false;
    // component.type = 'BankAccountCompliance';
    // fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.isBankAccount).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should show the Reset button when type is BankAccount', () => {
    setupComponent();
    // component.isBankAccount = false;
    // component.type = 'IbaCompliance';
    // fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.isBankAccount).toBe(false);
  });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved.  All I had to do is

```
 mockRoute.params = of({ id: '123', type: 'BankAccountCompliance'});
```